# When calling an object why do we have to initialize them to null (WSDL)

Tags: soap-api, wsdl, .net

I have generated an Enterprise WSDL to use for a .NET application that we will be using to interact with Salesforce. When looking to some tutorials, see the snippets:

**Why this:**

```
 SforceService SfdcBinding = null;
 LoginResult CurrentLoginResult = nulll;
 SfdcBinding = new SforceService();
```

**Instead of this:**

```
LoginResult CurrentLoginResult = new LoginResult();
SforceService SfdcBinding = new SforceService();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the place where we declare and where we use the variables. ( and also its one of those choice we make as a Developer). Its definitely not enforced by salesforce.

one of the scenarios i can think of..

If you declare them as class variables and use them inside a method,

- its good to assign them to null or leave them uninitialised during
  declaration at the class level..
- and initialise them inside the method where you use it.

this way the variable will get the memory allocated in heap only when the method is called.

Comment: oh I see, that's why they initialized an object to null when it's in the class level, and create and instance inside a method. I learned something today :)